# Facebook Realtime Updates Multiple Posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, real-time-updates

I'm doing some test to my application on Facebook, and one of the tests is a massive POSTS in a row to see what its the behavior o the app, but some of the posts are not triggering the Real Time Update event and others are getting the field time wrong.

> Example: One Event I receive comes with time=1349694666 but in
>   Facebook tables it says 1349694665, so when I do the query for it it
>   won't return the feed.

Can you guys know why or can you point me to an answer?
Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simple. Instead of doing the FQL to the table status do to the stream one. The values macth all the time, at least for me until now.